# How to add a character end of each variable with awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed, terminal

I have a tab deliminated file which I want to add "$" end of each variable, Can I do that with awk,sed or anything else?

**Example**
input:

```
a seq1 anot1
b seq2 anot2
c seq3 anot3
d seq4 anot4
```

I neet to have this:

output:

```
a$ seq1$ anot1$
b$ seq2$ anot2$
c$ seq3$ anot3$
d$ seq4$ anot4$
```

Any answer will be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed  's/[^ ]*/&$/g' filename
```

which replaces any non-space words with the word (&) followed by a $.

Oops!  You said tabs.  You can replace the above space with "\t" to use tab delimited.

```
sed 's/[^\t]*/&$/g' filename
```

Actually, even better, for tabs OR spaces:

```
sed 's/[^[:blank:]]*/&$/g' filename
```

Comment: Note that the `\t` shorthand works in GNU sed (i.e. most versions of Linux) but it is not universal. Doesn't work in OS X, FreeBSD, Solaris, etc. You might be able to get around this using bash's expansion quoting -- i.e. `$'...'`

Answer (score 3):

In bash alone:

```
while read line; do echo "${line//$'\t'/\$$'\t'}\$"; done < file
```

This hackish solution relies on two "special" things -- parameter expansion to do the replacement, and format expansion to allow the tabs to be parsed.

In awk, you can process fields much more safely:

```
awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {for(n=1;n<=NF;n++){$n=$n "$"}} 1' file
```

This works by stepping through each line of input and replacing each field with itself plus the dollar sign.  The BEGIN block insures that your output will use the same field separators as your input.  The `1` at the end is awk short-hand for "print the current line".

Answer (score 2):

late to the party...

another `awk` solution.  Prefix field and record separators with "$"

```
$ awk -F'\t' 'BEGIN{OFS="$"FS; ORS="$"RS} {$1=$1}1' file
```

Comment: Ooh, very nice. +1 for subtlety!

Answer (score 1):

awk is your friend :

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/$/,"$",$i);print}' file
```

or

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/$/,"$",$i);}1' file
```

**Sample Output**

```
a$ seq1$ anot1$
b$ seq2$ anot2$
c$ seq3$ anot3$
d$ seq4$ anot4$
```

---

**What is happening here?**

1. Using a `for-loop` we iterate thru all the fields in a record.
2. We use the awk `sub` function to replace the `end` ie (`/$/`) with a `$` ie (`"$"`) for each record (`$i`).
3. Use `print` explicitly to print the record. Numeric `1` also represents the default action that is to print the record.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{gsub(/ /,"$ ")}{print $0 "$\r"}' file
a$ seq1$ anot1$
b$ seq2$ anot2$
c$ seq3$ anot3$
d$ seq4$ anot4$
```

What happens?
First replace spaces with dollar sign and new space.
Last insert dollar sign before the carriage return.

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, answers that only contain code and have no textual explanation, get flagged for the review queues. You can avoid this by adding a sentence or two of explanation.